# Type "Grid" does not support direct content

Tags: wpf

I created first Uno project in VS2019. Very first thing I tried to do and getting error. When trying to edit MainPage.xaml in Shared project, I'm trying to put textbblock under the  the error it gives is "Type "Grid" does not support direct content. Nowhere on web, I'm able to find the solution for this. So I'm stuck right after creating the project. Not allowing me to evaluate it any further.

The second issue is no control on Toolbox is available to drop in xaml file. All controls are grayed out.

I'm not sure if this is right place to report this issue, but frustrated. Spend about 2 hours already on internet to find the solution without any luck.

searched on internet, but can't find solution

```
<Page
    x:Class="UnoTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UnoTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Content>

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Hi!" Margin="20" FontSize="30" />
        </Grid>


    </Page.Content>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out this code and it should work, as you **can** put content directly into a grid.
It seems to be a software issue, reinstall or repair. Does this work in VS 2017 on your machine?

The only other documented case I could find is this one:

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:zdjcF5nw5GMJ:m.dlxedu.com/m/askdetail/3/f7bcccb0f93776e625433978e0cbce6a.html+&cd=2&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de